# How to mock or bypass the beforeInsert Domain Method while testing?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, grails-orm, spock

I need to test this controller action, which requires me to save a Product object. but the domain Product has a beforeInsert method, which I want to either bypass or mock. I tried to mock it with metaclass and it does not seem to work. I am working with Grails 2.3.6. Any ideas?

```
class Product implements Serializable, FavouriteStat, Reviewable {

String name
String longName
String friendlyUrl


static hasMany = [
        tags                    : Tag,
        labelMappings           : LabelMapping,
       ]


def beforeInsert() {
    if (!friendlyUrl) {
        friendlyUrl = createFriendlyUrl()
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?  And usually, showing the code for the domain in question (or a simplified version that still has the issue) is recommended.

Comment: Editing the question acc. to your recommendations.

Comment: Ok, you're close.  You say you want to bypass or mock... is there a reason you don't want the method to run?  Most of what I'm reading says metaclass overriding should work, can you put in your test that didn't work, including the code you used to mock the beforeInsert?  All of that will help.